# Null Pointer Exception in Array List- How do objects work?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I am having null pointer exception. Could you please assist me?
I am having problems with objects in the Array list. I don't know where is the issue.

- Main Class

  public class JavaApplication3 {

  ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {


       ArrayList<user> object=new ArrayList<user>();

     user[] obj=new user[3];

      obj[0].setName("S");

      obj[0].setNumber(5);

        obj[1].setName("7");

      obj[1].setNumber(6);
       object.add(obj[0]);

         object.add(obj[1]);
      System.out.println(object.get(0).getName());
      System.out.println(object.get(1).getName());





   }
  ```

  }
- And this is my user class:

  public class user {

  ```
   private int no;
   private String name;

     public int getNo() {
       return this.no;
   }

   public void setNumber(int no) {
       this.no = no;
   }


   public String getName(){

   return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(String S){

       this.name=name;

   }
  ```

  }

AND THIS IS MY ERROR:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:26)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\12.3\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: You need to instantiate each User before you can set any property.

Comment: You created an array of users user[] obj=new user[3];, but you forgot to create a user for each position, like user[0] = new User();

Comment: Can you help me fix the code?  I tied  user[0]=new user(); but still not working.

Comment: Constructor needed for user class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just convert this from S to name

```
 public void setName(String name){
    
        this.name=name;
    
    }
```

and change to this code

```
ArrayList<user> object=new ArrayList<user>();
 user[] obj=new user[3]; 
obj[0]=new user(); 
obj[2]=new user(); 
obj[0].setName("S"); 
obj[0].setNumber(5);
 obj[1]=new user(); 
obj[1].setName("7");
 obj[1].setNumber(6); 
object.add(obj[0]); 
object.add(obj[1]);
 System.out.println(object.get(0).getName()); System.out.println(object.get(1).getName());
```

Comment: Already done that but the problem is still there-

Comment: ArrayList<user> object=new ArrayList<user>();

  user[] obj=new user[3];
       obj[0]=new user();
       obj[2]=new user();
        obj[0].setName("S");
        
        obj[0].setNumber(5);

        obj[1]=new user();
          obj[1].setName("7");

        obj[1].setNumber(6);
         object.add(obj[0]);
         object.add(obj[1]);

        System.out.println(object.get(0).getName());
        System.out.println(object.get(1).getName());

Comment: this is solved your problem

Comment: you must add in your code obj[0]=new user(); and obj [1]=new user();